# Displaying booleans in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui

In Swagger UI, why do my boolean parameters appear to be shifted left, and the parameter name is shown twice? I have added a screenshot of my boolean parameter as well as an Integer parameter that works fine.

Here are the annotations I use on the method. They appear to be similar to me, unless I'm missing something.

```
@ApiParam(value="The business unit where the item was ordered", name="itemBusinessUnit", required = true)
        @RequestParam(required = true, value = "itemBusinessUnit") Integer itemBusinessUnit,
        @ApiParam(value="Whether or not this was requested via item search (often false)", name="viaItemSearch", required = true)
        @RequestParam(required = true, value="viaItemSearch") boolean viaItemSearch)
```

[image: Screenshot of Swagger]